# Why does Xcode 10 opens random file in right pane?

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard, xcode10

I'm have this problem in Xcode 10. 
When I am working on a storyboard and I want to open another file in the right pane, I usually do CMD + SHIFT + O and then ALT + ENTER to open the file in a new pane.

The problem is that Xcode won't open the file I am asking for, but opening a random file (AppDelegate for instance) and I have to manually access the file I was looking for. Is this normal? How can I solve this?